# Inserting JSON element in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains unique IDs on each line. These IDs correspond to a URL that I'm trying to query. The query will return JSON. Deeply nested into this JSON there is a field that I need to check, and if it has a certain value then I need to update a column in the dataframe

If I set it up to do a one-off, i can print the text I need without issue:

```
target = 'target'
rtext = json.loads(r.text)
rtext = rtext.get('fields').get('comment').get('comments')

for item in rtext:
    comments = json.dumps(item)
    comments = json.loads(comments)
    body = comments.get('body')
    if target in body:
        print(body)
```

But when I try to apply this to the dataframe, it takes FOREVER, and I end up with no results

```
target = 'target'

def jira1(id):
    r = requests.get(jira_url+str(id),auth=(auth))

    rtext = json.loads(r.text)
    rtext = rtext.get('fields').get('comment').get('comments')

    for item in rtext:
        comments = json.dumps(item)
        comments = json.loads(comments)
        body = comments.get('body')
        if target in body:
            return body



reviews = pd.read_csv("1.csv")
features = pd.read_csv("2.csv")
combo = pd.merge(reviews, features, on="Feature_key")

combo['test'] = combo['Feature_key'].apply(jira1)
combo.to_csv('combo.csv')
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong here... can anyone advise?

Thanks!

Comment: Add sample csv data.
And how many rows are you working with?

Comment: Please go through [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for quicker and appropriate response from the community.